Public Profile Historical Followers Count in Instagram Graph Api, return empty data
I executed an API like below:
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/17841419511101502/insights/?metric=follower_count&period=day&since=1712327764&until=1714401364&access_token={TOKEN}
Then the following value was returned
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/17841419511101502/insights?access_token={TOKEN}&pretty=0&since=1710254163&until=1712327763&metric=follower_count&period=day",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/17841419511101502/insights?access_token={TOKEN}&pretty=0&since=1714401365&until=1716474965&metric=follower_count&period=day"
  }
}

What I would like is to collect the history of followers for the past 30 days from a public profile, but I am not able to do so. Just for information, the profile ID (17841419511101502) is not linked to the Instagram account that is using the app.

If it's not linked, then I don't think you can get access to any insights data.

Thanks for the answer, so is there no way to collect the follower history of a public profile that I don't manage via the API?

No. Many account owners would probably not be too happy, if Facebook just freely gave that info out to their "competition."

Thanks again, and can you tell me how websites (https://app.notjustanalytics.com/analysis/fomedeque_deli) that show the history of public profiles have access? using scrapling?

Most likely, yes.
